# Incorrect column names in spark dataset

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, kryo

I have next case class:

```
case class Data[T](field1: String, field2: T)
```

I'm using kryo serializer with next implicits for it:

```
implicit def single[A](implicit c: ClassTag[A]): Encoder[A] = Encoders.kryo[A](c)

implicit def tuple2[A1, A2](implicit e1: Encoder[A1], e2: Encoder[A2]): Encoder[(A1, A2)] =
        Encoders.tuple[A1, A2](e1, e2)

...
```

And I tried to make next join:

```
val ds1 = someDataframe1.as[(String, T)].map(row => Data(row._1, row._2))
val ds1 = someDataframe2.as[(String, T)].map(row => Data(row._1, row._2))
ds1.joinWith(ds2, col("field1") === col("field1"), "left_outer")
```

After that I got next exception:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'field1' given input columns: [value, value];
```

What happened with column names in my datasets?

**UPD**:
when I called `ds1.schema` I got next output:

```
StructField(name = value,dataType = BinaryType, nullable = true)
```

I think that I have problem with kryo serialization (there is no schema metadata, case class was serialized just as single blob field without name). Also I noticed that all works good when `T` is kryo known class (Int, String) or case class. But when `T` is some Java bean I get my Data dataset schema as single blob unnamed field.

Spark version 1.6.1

Comment: I am getting a different error message (Spark version?). Anyway, have you tried `col("_1.field1") === col("_2.field2)` as the join condition? This way it is working for me.

Comment: @Beryllium check updated question, please

Answer (score 0):

You just created a dataset with only one column typed Data, and you cannot access the fields(fields1) inside this object.

```
dataframe: |value|
           |------
           |Data |
           |------
           |Data |
           |------
```

You may try this to convert your dataframe to dataest:
val ds1 = someDataframe1.as[Data]

```
dataframe: |field1|field2|
           |------
           |String|  T   |
           |------
           |String|  T   |
           |------
```

Or if you still want to use your dataframe, try to change the searching criteria：

```
ds.joinWith(ds2, df.col("value").field1 === df2.col("value").field2)
```